# Using RXJS how to determine the source of the subscription trigger?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Subscription that is updated from multiple components. I need to know when component B subscription execution is observed.

E.g.
Component A, subscribes
Component B, subscribes
Component C, subscribes

Component A, triggers change

Is there a way to determine who caused the trigger?

Comment: See trigger is nothing  but sending data to all those who are listening. So, in the data only you can create one property which tell the name of sender.

Comment: Just playing about but would this work for your use case?...[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-asrvrw)

Answer (score 0):

The content of the triggered observable can be used to tell which component triggered it.

- The triggering part saves it´s own name into the observable
- the triggered part reads the source out of the object

Answer (score 0):

Example you can do as follow:

```
sub = new Subject<any>();

shareData(data){
  this.sub.next(data);
}
//Component A
let temp = {
 sender: "component A",
 data: "data"
}
service.shareData(temp);
```